# Session Expiring Issue using ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: c#, session

My application is online but users are calling and are getting their session expired within 10 minutes. My form is large and through testing I found takes about 20 minutes to fill out. I have not yet added the below tag into web config.

```
<sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
```

My question is, do I have to add above tag into web config of live site? I want to increase my session time to 30 minutes. Will that fix this problem or are there other problems that could be causing this additionally? Will adding this tag cause active users to lose their current session?